# Как реализовать авторизацию через Google в Laravel, используя пакет socialite

Tags: php, laravel

Уже установил laravel socialite/google, используя команду 
        composer require socialiteproviders/google 
В папке vendor появились каталоги laravel/socialite и socialiteproviders. Как их использовать?Как реализовать авторизацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации же целый раздел есть по [Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite), на сайте провайдеров есть целый пошаговый [гайд](https://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/google.html).

1) Удаляете `Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider` из массива `providers[]` в `config\app.php`.

Добавляете `\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class` в массив `providers[]` в файле `config\app.php`.

2) Добавляете в `config/services.php`:

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_KEY'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI')
],
```

Дальше следуя документации указываете маршруты, ничего сложного.